# Disabling label without bar Highstock

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a column chart Highstock:
http://jsfiddle.net/txfnsubb/

When we change range to smaller values, sometimes it shows us a label of value w/o the bar. For example I see 30 bars and at the end label with 31. Is there a possibility to turn it off? To set chart to showing label only with bar.

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart: {
        marginTop: 140
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataGrouping: {
                approximation: "average"
            }
        }
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },
    navigator: {
        top: 40,
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return x[this.value];
                }
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            y: 50,
            max: 150,
            formatter: function () {
                return x[this.value];
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var s = [];
            var next = this.x + this.points[0].series.pointRange;
            if ((this.x + 1) == next) {
                s.push("<b>Position: " + (this.x + 1));
            } else {
                s.push("<b>Position: " + (this.x + 1) + "-" + next);
            }
            $.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
                s.push('<span style="color:#D31B22;font-weight:bold;">' + point.series.name + ' : <span>' + point.y.toFixed(2));
            });
            return s.join('<br/>');
        },
        shared: true
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'reactivity',
        data: data,
        showInLegend: false,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2,
            shared: true
        }
    }, {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'experiment 1',
        data: data2,
        color: 'green',
        visible: false,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }, {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'experiment 2',
        data: data3,
        color: 'red',
        visible: false,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }],
    legend: {
        enabled: true,
        margin: 0
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            type: 'millisecond',
            count: seqLength / 5,
            text: '0.25'
        }, {
            type: 'millisecond',
            count: seqLength / 3,
            text: '0.3'
        }, {
            type: 'millisecond',
            count: seqLength / 2,
            text: '0.5'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: '1.0'
        }],
        inputEnabled: false, // it supports only days
        selected: 4 // all
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean ? There are currently no Labels for your columns.

Comment: labels on xAxis, it shows sth the value on xAxis without the bar

Comment: Use [`tickPositioner`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner) where you can decide which ticks should be displayed. There isn't direct connection between bar and tick, for example when you don't see bar, you can see points from different series (when turning them on).